# Populate string on background and setting up an AutoCompleteTextBox

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, populate

I'm trying to to the following things:

- Retrieve all the option-values from an URL (working)
- Pass them to a String[] in my app (working)
- Set up an AutoCompleteTextBox with the values of this String Array (not working).

I leave here my piece of code:

```
protected Elements doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    try {

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://pedidos.pizzeriabritannia.com/index.asp?Opc=Registro").get();
        Elements options = doc.select("select#calle option");
        return options;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    return null;

}


protected void onPostExecute(Elements options){

    for (int i = 0; i < options.size(); i++){

        calles[i] = html2text(options.get(i).toString());
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Registro.this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,calles);
    acTextView.setThreshold(2);
    acTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The AutoCompleteTextBox should work as follows, for example:

If I write MA, it would suggest me MADRID, MALAGA, MASSACHUSETTS...

but it does not show anything. I'm sure that the String has been populated.

Any suggestion??

Comment: tried to dump calles array?

Comment: @Aldridge1991 where have you initialize your array?

Comment: Before OnCreate(). The string array gets the values it should take. The problem is when I try to set this string to the AutoCompleteTextBox

Comment: @Aldridge1991 set the breakpoint at ArrayAdapter.ArrayFilter.performFiltering() method and see whats going on

Comment: COuld you be more specific please? I can't understand

Comment: One more thing. If I set static values for the string it works. But it's not working if a do it dynamically

Comment: @Aldridge1991 dud you try other adapters? see my answer how to use CursorAdapter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858843/how-to-dynamically-add-suggestions-to-autocompletetextview-with-preserving-chara